# Alteryx RTool not giving output

Tags: r, alteryx

My code in Alteryx RTool is not producing the output.

```
Input <- read.Alteryx("#1")  # Even tried using this to change input data to data frame.Input <- read.Alteryx("#1", mode="data.frame") 

print(Input)                 # The input data is printed.

Output1 <- Input[Input$My_MONTH==max(Input$My_MONTH)-1 & !Input$CASE_ID %in% Input[Input$My_MONTH==max(Input$My_MONTH)-2,c("CASE_ID")],]
Output2 <- Input[Input$My_MONTH==max(Input$My_MONTH) & !Input$CASE_ID %in% Input[Input$My_MONTH==max(Input$My_MONTH)-1,c("CASE_ID")],]

write.Alteryx(Output1,2)
write.Alteryx(Output2,3)
```

The problem is `Output1` and `Output2` do not get any data.

Comment: Any reason to not write to ouput1 to 1, output2 to 2?

Comment: No specific reason.

Comment: Try, just after the input: `Input <- as.data.frame(Input, stringsAsFactors='False')`

Comment: The below lines have worked for me. Thanks, John.  

library("data.table")
Input3 <- read.Alteryx("#1")
Input3 <- as.data.table(Input3)